# Google Cloud Deployment Manager: add instances to instance group via yaml configuration

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sdk

I'm trying to create an unmanaged instanceGroup with several VM's in it via Deployment Manager Configuration (YAML file).

I can easily find docs about [addInstances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instanceGroups/addInstances) via Google API, but couldn't find docs about how to do this in a YAML file:

[instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/beta/instances)

[instanceGroups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/beta/instanceGroups)

What properties should be included in instances/instanceGroup resource to make it work?

Comment: Have you found a resolution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no possibility right now, to do it with gcloud deployment manager.

Answer (score 5):

The YAML below will create a compute engine instance, create an unmanaged instance group, and add the instance to the group.

```
resources:
- name: instance-1
  type: compute.v1.instance
  properties:
    zone: australia-southeast1-a
    machineType: zones/australia-southeast1-a/machineTypes/n1-standard-1
    disks:
    - deviceName: boot
      type: PERSISTENT
      diskType: zones/australia-southeast1-a/diskTypes/pd-ssd
      boot: true
      autoDelete: true
      initializeParams:
        sourceImage: projects/debian-cloud/global/images/debian-9-stretch-v20180716
    networkInterfaces:
    - network: global/networks/default
      accessConfigs:
      - name: External NAT
        type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT

- name: ig-1
  type: compute.v1.instanceGroup
  properties:
    zone: australia-southeast1-a
    network: global/networks/default

- name: ig-1-members
  action: gcp-types/compute-v1:compute.instanceGroups.addInstances
  properties:
    project: YOUR_PROJECT_ID
    zone: australia-southeast1-a
    instanceGroup: ig-1
    instances: [ instance: $(ref.instance-1.selfLink) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

This was tested and it seemed that while Google Deployment Manager was able to complete without issue having the following snippet:

```
{
  "instances":  [
    {
      "instance":  string
    }
  ]
}
```

it did not add the instances specified, but created the IGM.

However Terraform seems to be able to do it https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_instance_group.html

Answer (score 1):

I think @mcourtney answer is correct.

I just had this scenario and i used python template with yaml config to add instances to an un-managed instance group.

Here is the snippet of resource definition in my python template :

```
{
        'name': name + '-ig-members',
        'action': 'gcp-types/compute-v1:compute.instanceGroups.addInstances',
        'properties': {
            'project': '<YOUR PROJECT ID>',
            'zone' : context.properties['zone'], // Defined in config yaml
            'instanceGroup': '<YOUR Instance Group name ( not url )>',
            "instances": [
    {
      "instance": 'projects/<PROJECT ID>/zones/<YOUR ZONE>/instances/<INSTANCE NAME>'
    }
  ]            
        }
    }
```

Reference API is documented here :

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/beta/instanceGroups/addInstances

This is just an example. you can abstract all the hard coded things to either yaml configuration or variables at the top of python template.